# MacBook has poor Bluetooth range

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth

My current workspace setup is a black MacBook that is plugged into a 21" monitor, with a Wireless Apple Keyboard and Magic Trackpad, both connected with Bluetooth. The issue is, I cannot take the two input components more than 12 to 18 inches away without either adding a delay or losing the signal entirely.

Is this normal? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: My range is like 4 feet, unbelievable because with he same bluetooth speaker my phone can be 20 feet away 2012 macbookpro

Comment: How did u fix it?

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't normal.  Considering the age of the machine, I'd guess that it's a failing Bluetooth card.  [It could also be some sort of interference.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference_at_2.4_GHz#Bluetooth)

Answer (score 1):

If it is really a case of poor Bluetooth range and not any interference. It might be that the Bluetooth antenna is loose / disconnecting from the Bluetooth card causing poor reception. Might not be a bad idea to double check the cable and make sure its connected and not corroded, etc. Before replacing the Bluetooth card.

If you are a DIY'er here is some more information on disassembling your MacBook see [iFixit's guides for MacBooks](http://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook). Other wise take it to a Apple Store or an Apple Authorized Service Provider for help.

[image: Bluetooth Antenna MacBook pictured]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
* Use with open screen
* Use 5gHz network instead of 2.4gHz (or better use ethernet).

This should help. If not - try the Bluetooth Diagnostics Utility.app